# How to determine when NSTextFieldCell isHighlighted has no focus?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I've subclassed a NSTextFieldCell (inside a NSTableView) to draw a custom foreground color when a cell (ie row) is selected (eg isHighlighted is true) and everything works fine.

The problem is when the table view loses the focus I want to draw the selected rows with a different color, how can I determine if the table view containing the cell isn't the first responder inside drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView*)controlView?

My current code is

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView*)controlView {
        NSColor* textColor = [self isHighlighted]
                 ? [NSColor alternateSelectedControlTextColor]
                 : [NSColor darkGrayColor];
}
```

Comment: I also really want an answer to this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way I've found that doesn't make you deal with responders (since sometimes the `controlView`'s superview is the responder or some nonsense) is to use the editor:

```
BOOL isEditing = [(NSTextField *)[self controlView] currentEditor] != nil;
```

Easy as that!

Comment: The question is pretty old and I've resolved as you say so thanks, answer accepted :)

Comment: And also check the window is key? Or is that unnecessary? `&& [self.window isKeyWindow]`

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution that uses the firstResponder, it is simple and seems efficient

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView*)controlView {
        NSColor* textColor;

        if ([self isHighlighted]) {
            textColor = [[controlView window] firstResponder] == controlView 
                     ? [NSColor alternateSelectedControlTextColor]
                     : [NSColor yellowColor];
        } else {
            textColor = [NSColor darkGrayColor];
        }

        // use textColor
        ...
        ...
        [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
    }
```

Comment: I found that too, but it does not check the case when the application is deactivated. Can't believe there isn't a better way.

Comment: You just need to register for the notifications `NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification` and `NSApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and then call `-setNeedsDisplay:` on the table view in the method you've configured to handle the notification.

Comment: And I guess also register for windows becoming active and inactive? Seems like a lot to do for a standard cell focus thing. There must be a better way hidden inside AppKit… Or maybe time to encapsulate it into a component / category.

Comment: Actually `showsFirstResponder` is a better way to check if a cell is highlighted because it also catched click events.

Answer (score 2):

one more thing, the above code is perfect, however if you have multiple windows
you will need to check if your window is key

```
        if (controlView && ([[controlView window] firstResponder] == controlView) && [[controlView window] isKeyWindow]) {
            [attributes setObject:[NSColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
        }
```